# Linked List in C: Delete Second Node and Free Memory

Tags: c, linked-list

For some reason, if I have a linked list that looks like 3->2->1->0, and I called deleteSecond(head), I get 3->1->0->0. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
  int data;
  struct ListNode *next;
} *LinkedList;

int deleteSecond(LinkedList list) {
  if (list == NULL || list->next == NULL)
    return 0;
  int val = list->next->data;
  LinkedList second = list->next;
  list->next = list->next->next;
  free(second);
  return val;
}

int main() {
  LinkedList head = NULL;
  head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    LinkedList newNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    newNode->data = i;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
  LinkedList ptr = head;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
  deleteSecond(head);
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", head->data);
    head = head->next;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I believe my deleteSecond function should be correct. I create a pointer to my second node, and then I make the head->next = head->next->next, and the I free the pointer to the second node. I don't know why I have two 0's at the end of the list.

Comment: And why you `typedef` a pointer? It's ...well..you get it by now..hard to handle

Comment: `head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));` and here you did just what you shouldn't.

Comment: Always use `head = malloc(sizeof *head);`, that saves you from this problem, and from re-typing the proper type name in general ... as long as you remember that asterisk, of course. :)

Comment: The problem is that you have allocated `head` before the loop, and you never assigned anything to its `data` or `next`. You should keep `head` set to `NULL` before entering the loop in which you populate the list. This would fix the problem ([demo](https://ideone.com/mriS5A)).

Comment: For one thing,. after deleting one element you should loop 3 times, not 4. better yet

Comment: Sorry about that, I hit enter too soon. For one thing, after deleting one element you should loop 3 times, not 4. better yet for(ptr=head; ptr != NULL; ptr=ptr->next) would work better, but you have to make sure the last struct's next element is assigned to NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an empty node `head` which is creating problem. Your last node should point to `NULL`. So initializing `head = NULL` is the correct one.

```
  LinkedList head = NULL;
//  head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    LinkedList newNode = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
    newNode->data = i;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
head = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
```

This is wrong. Correct would be

```
head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

Then again same way it would be

```
LinkedList newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

Now let's see what you did here.

`head`'s data or link attribute is never initialized. So you get undefined behavior accessing it.

This is the code you wanted to write if you want to allocate memory to `head`.

```
...
int main(void) {
  LinkedList head = NULL;
  head =  malloc(sizeof(*head));
  if( head == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
    exit(1);
  }
  head->next = NULL;
  head->data = 2017; // dummy data.
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    LinkedList newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if( newNode == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->data = i;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
  ...
  ...
  deleteSecond(head);
  while (head != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", head->data);  // prints 2017 also. But deletes the node that was in second position.
    head = head->next; 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here we have used one extra node for holding the dummy data. Yes! it's not needed. This dummy node is doing nothing significant other than providing an next link for the `newNodes` which is not needed if you just use `head` as `LinkedList` or `struct LinkedNode*` and allocates no memory to it. It suggests we can eliminate than and simply use the pointer to `struct ListNode` namely `head`.

Then the code will be simply like

```
LinkedList head = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    LinkedList newNode =  malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if( newNode == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
        exit(1);
    }
    newNode->data = i;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
  }
```

There are couple of things you can consider

- **Don't** hide pointers under typedef.
- **Do** check the return value of `malloc`.
- **Do** free the memory that you allocate after you are done working with it.

The code can be written this way also. It doesn't use the pointer under `typedef` and modularize the reusable codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ListNode {
    int data;
    struct ListNode *next;
} ListNode;
void freeMemList(ListNode *head){
    ListNode *temp;
    while(head!=NULL){
       temp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(temp);
   }
}
int deleteSecond(ListNode * list) {
    if (list == NULL || list->next == NULL)
         return 0;
    int val = list->next->data;
    ListNode * second = list->next;
    list->next = list->next->next;
    free(second);
    return val;
}
void printList(ListNode *head){
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
struct ListNode * addNodes(struct ListNode* head, int n){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ListNode * newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
        if( newNode == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
            exit(1);
        }
        newNode->data = i;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    return head;
}
int main(void) {
    ListNode * head = NULL;

    head = addNodes(head,4); 

    printList(head);
    printf("********\n");
    int valDeleted = deleteSecond(head);
    printf("%s %d\n","Value deleted ", valDeleted );
    printList(head);
    freeMemList(head);
    return 0;
}
```